# Comunicação entre C\C++ ADDON e NodeJS

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Esto a tentar implementar um servidor capaz de fazer reconhecimento de fala. Mas esta última parte tem de ser implementada através de um C\C++ Addon. Neste momento, estou a gravar o ficheiro wav no servidor e a passar o nome ao addon:

```
var obj1 = julius("nomeficheiro.wav","lista|palavras|possiveis");
word = obj1.recog;//resultado
cm = obj1.cm;//confiança no resultado
```

No entanto a minha intenção é: não escrever ficheiros no disco e fazer tudo através da memória. O reconhecedor de fala aceita como entrada possivel o stdin. É possível fazer um pipe entre o C\C++ addon e o NodeJs?

Comment: Acredito que é mais fácil usar um socket...Muitos dos módulos que comunicam o C++ com o Node que eu conheço usam socket.

Comment: Sim é possível. Node.js possui uma infraestrutura para execução de processos. Esta infraestrutura é reunida no módulo [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). No node.js você pode realizar o procedimento de piping com um child process suprindo um readable stream como stdin. Para mais documentação, visitar a seção [subprocess.stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdin) da documentação oficial.

Comment: Além da integração através de subprocessos com o módulo [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) e Unix Domain Sockets com o módulo [Net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_ipc_support). É possível utilizar outra técnica denominada integração nativa e isso é feito utilizando a infraestrutura de criação de [módulos nativos em C++ disponível em Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).